# Pip3 version not being updated in WSL

Tags: python, terminal, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to update my pip version in WSL Ubuntu 20.04, I update it using the command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

It does show that the current pip version is 21.1.2 as shown in the screenshot,
but if I do `pip3 --version`, I get 20.0.2.

Why is it acting like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's something different going on around here. Running `python3 -m pip` just updates the local package (that is only for you) on Linux (or WSL). Run `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and it'll get updated for everyone and `pip3 --version` will evaluate to the new version.

Comment: Thank you, although I did got some trouble when it was uninstalling the previous version. It's as follows "Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr                               Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall."

Comment: Was it a warning or error? If it was an warning then no need to worry.

Comment: It was just a warning I suppose, But yeah it worked out well. Thank you